# Calculate spatial GINI coefficient for land use

Tags: spatial-analyst, spatial-statistics, geostatistical-analyst, land-use

I am interested in calculating an index of agricultural land inequality for Brazil. I'm thinking that a GINI coefficient would be a good approach given traditional uses of GINI. I have a data set for all municipalities in Brazil that consists of four columns for each municipality (rows): 1) number of family farms, 2) area occupied by small farm land use; 3) number of non-family farms; 4) area occupied by non-family farms.

What's I'm really hoping to attain is a value that can represent the relations between percent area occupied by non-family farms in comparison with family farms.

I can obtain the total area of the municipality from municipality shapefile, but I don't think it makes sense to have a simple ratio of non-family farm area/municipality area as there will be various other forms of land use.

Any suggestions on how to calculate a spatial GINI using this data set, or a different statistic that makes more sense?